# ExtJS 3.4 callback function after ajax request

Tags: ajax, extjs, store

I have a store :

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'list',
        url: '../myProject/getData.ajax',
        baseParams:{
            date:'',
        },
        fields: rec,
        totalProperty:'totalCount',
        pruneModifiedRecords:true,
        autoLoad : false,   
        listeners:{
            load:function(){
                globalMask.hide();
            }
        } 
    });
```

And after button pressed i load store with a function :

```
function storeLoad(){
    store.baseParams =  {
            date:date.getRawValue(),
        },
    store.load({
        params  :{start:0, limit:100},
        callback: function (response,options,success) {
                    if (success){
                        var res =  Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText); 
                        if(res.msj != null){
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert("Sonuç",res.msj);

                        }
                    } else{
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert("Error","Error message : "+response.statusText+". Try again later!!! ");
                    }
                    console.log("response:"+response);
                    console.log("op:"+options);
                    console.log("success:"+success);
                    console.log("res:"+res);
                    console.log("res.mesaj:"+res.msj);
            }

    });
}
```

And after this in console returns like this :

> response:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object]
>
> op:[object Object]
>
> success:true
>
> res:
>
> res.msj:undefined

how can i handle this? Why can not decode response? And i want to load store after success but store loads itself.How can i use  Callback success and failure ?
Store root is true,it loads but i can not load it after success or failure ?

Comment: What is the actual JSON response you get from the server?

Comment: A json array with 'list' key.

["list":[all data],"success":true/false,"totalCount":110,"msj":"Done/Error"]

Comment: try running your JSON resposne through http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: see your json response in the browsers console window? copy that and paste it in to the large text box on that site, it will then validate your JSON and let you know if there are any errors. If your JSON is invalid it cannot be decoded properly

Comment: it is valid, because grid is show it true. Only in callback is not decode.

Answer (score 0):

response argument in your callback function is not json response from the server. This is an array of loaded records, view [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-load)

Comment: If it is not json response, how to does it load grid rows correctly? Response is a json array i am sure. response is : ["list":[all data],"success":true/false,"totalCount":110,"msj":"Done/Error"]

Comment: Reader decode JSON and generate data in the store, callback function receive this data. What you want to do in callback function.

Comment: I write the code above. I want to load store after callback's received data and give some alerts to user a message which is  i can't decode.

Answer (score 0):

In the reader of store add Ext.data.DataReader.messageProperty = "msj", view first example of [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader) and add alert in listener "load" of store.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the console.log with string and object. Try console.log(response) instead of console.log("response:"+response);

Try this in your console log you will understand:

Execute:

```
    var test = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
```

Execute:

```
   

     console.log(test);
```

Output:

```
     Object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Execute:

```
console.log("response" + test);
```

Output:

```
 response[object Object]
```

If you do that, you will be able to navigate the objects. Maybe your code is already right.